# How can I wrap my algorithm max value into function?

Tags: java, arraylist, model

I want to wrap my algorithm of MAX value into function. I have a few the same algorithms which I need to find max width of each column table. The main problem is that I have Mentor class which is model (MVC). There I have setters and getters. I don't know how wrap code which use getters of Mentor class. I iterate by collection and I use getters to get access to each instance variable.

This code below I want wrap into only one function.

```
List<Mentor> mentorList = managerDatabase.selectAllFromMentorsTable();

maxLengthID = mentorList.get(0).getId();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getId();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthID){
        maxLengthID = potentialMax;
    }
}
//for example: code below this line is ALGORITHM MAX VALUE

maxLengthFirstName = mentorList.get(0).getFirstName().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getFirstName().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthFirstName){
        maxLengthFirstName = potentialMax;
    }
}

//code above this line
maxLengthLastName = mentorList.get(0).getLastName().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getLastName().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthLastName){
       maxLengthLastName = potentialMax;
    }

}

maxLengthNickName = mentorList.get(0).getNickName().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getNickName().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthNickName){
       maxLengthNickName = potentialMax;
    }
}

maxLengthPhoneNumber = mentorList.get(0).getPhoneNumber().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
   int potentialMax = mentor.getPhoneNumber().length();
   if(potentialMax > maxLengthPhoneNumber){
       maxLengthPhoneNumber = potentialMax;
   }
}

maxLengthEmail = mentorList.get(0).getEmail().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getEmail().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthEmail){
        maxLengthEmail = potentialMax;
    }
}

maxLengthCity = mentorList.get(0).getCity().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getCity().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthCity){
        maxLengthCity = potentialMax;
    }
}

maxLengthFavouriteNumber = mentorList.get(0).getFavouriteNumber().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getFavouriteNumber().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthFavouriteNumber){
        maxLengthFavouriteNumber = potentialMax;
    }
}
```

And here is my model Mentor class

```
package codecool.Model;

public class Mentor {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String city;
    private String favouriteNumber;

    public Mentor(){

    }

    public Mentor(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String nickName, String phoneNumber, String email, String city, String favouriteNumber){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.city = city;
        this.favouriteNumber = favouriteNumber;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFavouriteNumber() {
        return favouriteNumber;
    }

    public void setFavouriteNumber(String favouriteNumber) {
        this.favouriteNumber = favouriteNumber;
    }
}
```

Something like that I want wrap into function:

```
maxLengthNickName = mentorList.get(0).getNickName().length();
for(Mentor mentor: mentorList){
    int potentialMax = mentor.getNickName().length();
    if(potentialMax > maxLengthNickName){
       maxLengthNickName = potentialMax;
    }
}
```

As you can see code with algorithm max value is repeated a few time.

Comment: One approach might to use something like a visitor pattern, where by you define an interface which takes a reference to a single `Mentor` and returns a `int` value of list size.  Then you method would just be about looping over a list and calling that interface, something similar to `Collections.sort`, where you can pass a comparator to adjust the algorthim

Comment: `mentorList.stream().map(Mentor::getNickName).mapToInt(String::length).max()` gives you the length of the longest nickname. Just wrap it in a method, taking the method reference to extract the string as a parameter.

Comment: Andy Turner. First Time I see that code. Can you tell me what should be parameter? And if you can I would like something easier, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Streams, which will do it for you.

For example:

```
 maxLengthNickname = mentorList
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(mentor -> mentor.getNickname().getLength())
                .max();
```

The disadvantage however is that in both your example and in this case you will be looping through the same loop multiple times.

Maybe makes more sense to do one loop and do them all inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would generalize this with a method such as:

```
public <T> int max(List<T> list, ToIntFunction<T> toInt) {
    int max = toInt.applyAsInt(list.get(0));
    for(T t : list) {
        if(toInt.applyAsInt(t) > max) {
            max = toInt.applyAsInt(t);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

And then everytime you need to call it (For example with a `String`) you can do:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hello", "one", "four", "biggest");
ToIntFunction<String> length = (str) -> str.length();
int biggest = max(list, length);
```

Or pass it in directly via a method reference:

```
int biggest = max(list, String::length);
```

Which will return 7

Or java 8+ you can do:

```
public <T> int max(List<T> list, ToIntFunction<T> toInt) {
     return list.stream().mapToInt(toInt).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Which will keep you from having to write the same loop over and over

---

Documentation for [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html)